# Setting up Umbraco with Mercurial

Tags: version-control, mercurial, umbraco

I have started to build a website using Umbraco CMS. We are two people working on it. A **developer** (creating document types and custom controls) and a **designer** (CSS and Javascript)

We are working remotely, hence I setup a Mercurial account to sync our work. What is the best way to work in parallel without facing any obstacles going forward?

What things should I keep in mind when setting up an Umbraco project over Mercurial for simultaneous work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we have used mercurial for one of our umbraco projects. What we have done is we created separate branches for each work and will work parallel. After completing the work will merge into default branch.

If both users are using same db, then it will be okay to work with separate branches. But if both are using separate db then you need to find some way to synchronize your database.

I think since you both working on different sections ie one in document types and custom sections and other in css and javascript , i think its better you can work one a single branch and will update your solutions whenever there is a need. I think it will not create much conflicts since you both are working on different sections.

Answer (score 0):

I'd echo the previous comments... Share the database for an easier workflow since both users are going to be working on mostly separate concerns.

For instances where you are sharing doc type creation, or the content tree, the code-first build approach can *really* help (using uSiteBuilder)
http://usitebuilder.vegaitsourcing.rs/

Also, Courier will help get your databases synced if your project can afford the modest licence costs, without getting into the mess of SQL synchronisation.  (It's on the official umbraco.com site)

You'll probably need a good ignore file, too.  Pete Duncanson's is a good place to start:
http://offroadcode.com/blog/2012/4/5/mercurial-ignore-file-for-umbraco/